# como elimino listbox/Entry en tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

hola estoy haciendo un lista de tareas y me puse a programar la opcon de eliminar, cuando la programe sabia que me iria a salir un error, tal como yo pense fue este:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\programa1\untitled1.py", line 17, in borrar
    tareas.delete(ingresar.get())
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3174, in delete
    self.tk.call(self._w, 'delete', first, last)
_tkinter.TclError: bad listbox index "fhjdsjhfgsj": must be active, anchor, end, @x,y, or a number.
```

mas o menos comprendi e error e intente arreglarlo por mi mismo de todas las ideas que se me ocurrieron pero no funcionaron. me gustaria que me dijeran cua es el error ya que se loas agradeceria mucho.

mi codigo:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

ventana=Tk()
ventana.title("portafilex")
ventana.geometry("800x700")


#codigos

def ingrese():
    if B1==B1:
        tareas.insert(END, ingresar.get())

def borrar():
    if B2==B2:
        tareas.delete(ingresar.get())
        


#partes del programa
ingresar = Entry(ventana,width=30)
ingresar.grid(column=0, row=0)

#botones
B1=Button(ventana, text="ingresar", height=2,width=9, command=ingrese)
B1.grid(column=1, row=0)

B2=Button(ventana, text="eliminar", height=2,width=9, command=borrar)
B2.grid(column=1, row=8)
#lista
tareas=Listbox(ventana,height=35,width=100)
tareas.insert(0,"prueva")
tareas.grid(column=2, row=516)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Pasa que el método delete del listbox espera que le pases de argumento la ubicación del elemento. Por ejemplo si "hola mundo" está en la posición 2, el comando debe llamarse de este modo: `tareas.delete(2)`. Los argumentos del comando serían: `tulistbox.delete(desde, hasta)`. Más info de como funcionan los listbox aquí: https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/lista-listbox-en-tkinter/

Para borrar un elemento que sea igual al contenido del entry en la lista tendrías que hacer así:

```
def borrar():
    # No entiendo por que pones este condicional, ya que siempre dará verdadero. El boton siempre será igual a si mismo. Juan siempre es igual a el mismo.
    if B2==B2:
        contenido_entry = ingresar.get()

        # Uso la función enumerate para enumerar cada item iniciando desde el 0. Esto resulta en algo similar (no igual) a ((0, 'item1'), (1, 'item2'))
        # Con tulistbox.get(desde, hasta) obtenemos los items. Al poner desde 0 y hasta "end" le indicamos que nos devuelva todos.
        # Posteriormente separo cada item del iterable resultante en index (la ubicación del item) e item (el item del listbox)
        for index, item in enumerate(tareas.get(0, "end")):
            if(item == contenido_entry):
                # Si encuentro un item que coincida con el contenido del entry, borro dicho item teniendo su ubicación.
                # Notese que si ningún item coincide con el contenido del entry, no va a suceder nada.
                tareas.delete(index)
                break
```

Es esto lo que querías lograr? Si no es así comentamelo y haré una respuesta que sea más cercana a lo que buscas.